# How to say something is a little more than the amount it should be?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

Suppose we want to organize a study group of no more than five people but it turns out that seven people want to join in. In this case, the leader says:

> We only need five people in this study group. Seven people _____.

Here I don't want to use "are too many". I want to put an expression weaker than "too many".

Comment: Thanks, but please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *a bit (too) much* or *a little (too) much* might work here. I couldn't find an entry for *a little (too) much*, but it should be equivalent to *a bit (too) much*.

> [a bit much](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/a-bit-much) in American English
>   too much
>   (Collins Dictionary)

Warning! Sometimes the phrases are used to show that you are annoyed or displeased with something or someone. It can also mean you think something or someone was unreasonable or unfair.

> - [a bit much](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/a-bit-much)
>     phrase
>     If you say that something is a bit much, you are annoyed because you think someone has behaved in an unreasonable way.
>     [informal , feelings]
>     • Her stage outfit of hot pants, over-the-knee boots and a tube top was a bit much.
>     (Collins Dictionary)
> - [a bit (too) much](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+bit+much)
>     unreasonable or unfair
>     *I think it's a bit much to expect anyone to play three tennis matches in one day. Bill went at four in the morning and had to wait four hours to get in, but that was just a bit too much for me.*
>     (TFD)
> - [a bit much](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+bit+much)
>     mod. more than enough; more than good taste allows.
>     *That was a bit much, Paul. After all there is such a thing as good taste.*
>     (TFD)

Comment: Is there a euphemistic way to say it without leaving people the impression that I am annoyed?

Comment: I don't think it sounds "annoyed", especially if you say it in a nice tone. I think it sounds softer than "are too many", which is what I think you meant by "weaker".

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about individuals we can say **a few too many**.

P.S. It's not clear what your intentions are in trying to find a "weaker" version of "too many".

Comment: Actually I am looking for a euphemistic way to say it without leaving people the impression that I am annoyed.

Comment: So you want to turn away some people but in a good-natured way?

Comment: Something like that~~~the way politicians usually do.